# Why does the Orville have the ability to make it rain on the bridge?

Tags: the-orville

In *The Orville*, 2x06 "A Happy Refrain", Isaac tells the titular ship to turn on the environmental systems on the bridge, causing it to start pouring rain.

Having a wet and slippery bridge seems like something that would be a distraction at best and a danger at worse. Imagine it the bridge were to start raining while dealing with the Krill!

So why does the Orville even have the ability to make it rain on the bridge?

[image: The Orville Gordon Malloy "We are without a doubt the weirdest ship in the fleet"]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a *standard* feature. Isaac had to programme a subroutine to accomplish it.

Comment: Well given that in the past Isaac cut off one of Gordon Malloy's legs just for the sake of a practical joke, I'd say that anything is possible,

Comment: Make it **rain**!   Whoop, whoop!  \`\o/\`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key words are tells and environmental systems Isaac specifically requested (or possibly hacked the environmental system) to make it rain this is not something that would happen accidentally and I seriously doubt anyone would request it during a battle.

As to why it can rain well what is rain, rain is moisture condensed from the atmosphere that falls visibly in separate drops, any environmental system worth its salt should be able to easily move moisture anywhere anyone wants it.

TL;DR

The environmental system controls the environment with the right programming/hacking skills you can get it to do pretty much anything.